# Consulta nodemailer nodejs

Tags: nodejs, proxy, nodemailer

Estoy tratando de enviar un mensaje en una red con un proxy activo 
ip proxy:192.168.2.1:3128

Configuro mis opciones en nodemailer

```
var smtpConfig = {
    host: 'smtp.gmail.com',
    port: 465,
      auth: {
        user: mailconfig.email,
        pass: mailconfig.password
    },
    //proxy config 
    // assumes a HTTP proxy running on port 3128 
    proxy: 'http://192.168.2.1:3128'
};

var smtptransport=nodemailer.createTransport(smtpConfig);
```

Pero me sale el siguiente error:

> Invalid response from proxy 403

Ya revise todo , y no se en que pueda estar el error.

Answer (score 0):

El código de estatus 403 indica que la solicitud al Proxy requiere autentificacion. En el código de ejemplo no se ve que pases credenciales en los detalles del proxy. Este debe ser el problema